# SQL need to join tables and return values with conditions

Tags: sql, date, join, multiple-conditions

I have two tables that I need to join & aggregate.

Table 1 has 1 row per date & vehicle
Table 2 can have multiple rows per date & vehicle

I want to join on date and vehicle, and retrieve the min(table2.end_times) that is greater than the table1.max_job_complete_date. The desired value won't necessarily be the maximum end_times from table2, so I can't simply use a row_number() over partition by...

[simplified visual of the two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwfSj.png)

I tried the following, but this doesn't necessarily pull the max end_time specifically for that date & driver.

```
select
a."date",
a.vehicle,
a.max_job_complete_date,
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b
on b."date" = a."date"
and b.vehicle = a.vehicle
where b.end_times >= (select(max_load_complete_time from table1))
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You are only selecting columns from the first table of a `left join`, so it doesn't seem like `b` is being used at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
a."date",
a.vehicle,
a.max_job_complete_date,
min(b.end_time)
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b
on b."date" = a."date"
and b.vehicle = a.vehicle
Group by
a."date",
a.vehicle,
a.max_job_complete_date
Having b.end_time>a.max_job_complete_date
```

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery might be the simplest solution:

```
select a.*,
       (select min(b.date)
        from table2 b
        where b.vehicle = a.vehicle and
              b."date" = a."date" and
              b.end_time >= a.max_load_complete_time
       ) as next_b_date
from table1 a;
```

Comment: thank you, this did exactly what i was hoping/needed!